Ubuntu GUI behaviour in 22.04 when using super key and left/right cursor keys changed from 20.04
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 24.04. Really enjoying the latest version, but one bothersome new "feature" is less than ideal at least from my opinion. I have an ultra-wide monitor and for the last few years have appreciated being able to have 2 documents or browser etc. open in equally sized windows, side by side on the screen at the same time. Historically this has worked beautifully in 18.04 and 20.04. Using the super-key and left/right cursor keys I can quickly resize and move a window around at leisure on the screen, without disrupting any workflow underneath the screen (IE other half or full screen windows).
Now I see that Ubuntu have decided to make the user interface operate more like Windows (that in fact drives me nuts with Windows) whereby when I use the super key and cursor key to resize a window and shift it over, Ubuntu/Windows automatically prompts you in terms of what to do with the "unused" portion of the screen! I don't want that. Traditionally Ubuntu would simply expose whatever was sitting behind the application currently in focus. EG if I had LibreCalc in focus (full screen) with Thunderbird full screen behind it, and I then use super-key and right cursor key, my LibreCalc window would "half size" and shift to the right, exposing thunderbird emails on the left hand side of the screen. Thunderbird would still be full screen, but of course be partially obscured by LibreCalc on the right. I'm totally happy with that, and find it really quick and snappy to click on a given window and maximize or half size it and shift it around on the screen while leaving everything behind it as is. Now Ubuntu prompts you to decide what other application you want to resize and show on the left!
How can I disable this "Windows type" behavior and revert back to the traditional GUI mechanism? Much less frustrating from a user experience perspective.
Here's an image to demonstrate what I personally feel is a step in the wrong direction for the Ubuntu GUI (behavior) for an otherwise outstanding operating system.It's what you see on the left half of the screen that I wish to disable/remove.


No comments after months, sigh. Guess I'm forced to live with this irritation
